# List with multiple different types

Tags: c#, generic-list

Is it possible to store different types of objects in a List?
For example

```
public class Test
{
  public List<T> GenericList {get;set;}
}
public class TestA
{
  public String Value {get;set;}
}
public class TestB
{
  public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

I want to be able to fill the GenericList in the Test class with both TestA and TestB objects.
Is this possible?

Comment: No. For this, you would need a common base class, or a List<object> or a List<dynamic>.

Comment: Have both `TypeA` and `TypeB` inherit from the same base type/interface and then have `List<BaseType> GenericList`. Less nice - list of objects

Comment: Using a `List<object>` or other shared base class.

Comment: This [solution](https://gist.github.com/rob-alem/dbcf6959dfbf6efc16d26378677209be) works